# Check if cookies are enabled for login on every page

Tags: django, authentication, session-cookies

I have a login form on every page. If login fails because cookies are disabled, I want to show the user a message asking them to enable cookies. I have created this **middleware**:

```
class CheckCookiesEnabled(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_anonymous():
            request.session.set_test_cookie()
        return
```

In my login view, I check for `request.session.test_cookie_worked()` and log in only if it did, otherwise I want to display the message.

```
if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
    request.session.delete_test_cookie()
    # Log in 
else:
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'errors': "Login failed (enable cookies to login)"}), mimetype = 'application/json')
```

The thing is, `request.session.test_cookie_worked()` seems to be always true; Django seems to be able to set the test cookie even though cookies are disabled in the browser. Any ideas why and how to fix this? Or is there a better way to check if the browser has cookies enabled?

By the way: If I `set_test_cookie()` on every request, does Django always set a new cookie or only if there isn't already one?

Comment: I know about that, @cathy, and that's what I did. But my question remains: Why is `test_cookie_worked()` true even though cookies are disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using JavaScript:

```
function cookies_enabled() {
    if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
        return true;
    } else if (navigator.cookieEnabled === undefined) {
        document.cookie = "testcookie";
        if (cookie_present("testcookie"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Works just fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `set_test_cookie` in `process_response` of your middleware, not the `process_request`. `test_cookie_worked` is always true because you're always add it yourself by populating the `request.session` with the "cookie" at the `process_request` - it is executed before the control goes to the view.

Comment: Ah, that might work. Anyway, I ended up using JavaScript, which seems somewhat simpler. But thanks!